# Is Core Video available on the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I have some video that I'd like to overlay text on top.

Is Core video available on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The only supported method for playing videos is MPMoviePlayerController.

Answer (score 0):

iphone OS 3.0 also supports HTTP streaming which is really helpful because it works through firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

It is, and what you mention is now possible, though not all of the Core Video methods are available.